# Victory Chart clickable bar

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

I'm building a graph and I want to be able to click a bar to show some info when clicked, but even though I inserted all information set in the Victory Chart page is not working, could anyone help me, here is the code

```
<VictoryStack colorScale={['#533AED']}>
              {myWeekDataset &&
                myWeekDataset.map((data, i) => {
                  console.log(data)
                  return (
                    <VictoryBar
                    style={{data: {strokeWidth: 0}}}
                    cornerRadius={{
                      top: 10,
                      bottom: 10,
                    }}
                    events={
                      [
                        {
                          target: "data",
                          eventHandlers: {
                            onClick: () => {
                              return [{
                                target: "data",
                                mutation: (props) => {
                                  console.log('>>>>CLICKED', props)
                                  
                                }
                              }]
                            },
                          },
                        },
                      ]
                    }

                    data={data}
                    key={i}
                    />
                  );
                })}
            </VictoryStack>
```

this is the data

```
const myWeekDataset = [
    [
      {x: moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('ddd'), y: 8},
      {x: moment().subtract(6, 'days').format('ddd'), y: 10},
      {x: moment().subtract(5, 'days').format('ddd'), y: 6},
      {x: moment().subtract(4, 'days').format('ddd'), y: 7},
      {x: moment().subtract(3, 'days').format('ddd'), y: 4},
      {x: moment().subtract(2, 'days').format('ddd'), y: 8},
      {x: moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('ddd'), y: 9},
      
    ],
  ];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code in the following example

```
import React from "react";
import { VictoryChart, VictoryBar, VictoryStack, VictoryTheme } from "victory";

const genRandomData = () => parseInt(Math.random() * 100);

const myWeekDataset = [
  [
    { x: "Wed", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Thu", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Fri", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Sat", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Sun", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Mon", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Tue", y: genRandomData() }
  ],
  [
    { x: "Wed", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Thu", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Fri", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Sat", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Sun", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Mon", y: genRandomData() },
    { x: "Tue", y: genRandomData() }
  ]
];

export default function App() {
  events = [
    {
      target: "data",
      childName: "DataSet-0",
      eventHandlers: {
        onClick: () => [
          {
            mutation: (props) => {
              console.log("Click on first stack");
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      target: "data",
      childName: "DataSet-1",
      eventHandlers: {
        onClick: () => [
          {
            mutation: (props) => {
              console.log("Click on second stack");
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <VictoryChart theme={VictoryTheme.material} domainPadding={{ y: 40 }}>
        <VictoryStack events={this.events}>
          {myWeekDataset.map((dataSet, idx) => (
            <VictoryBar key={idx} data={dataSet} name={`DataSet-${idx}`} />
          ))}
        </VictoryStack>
      </VictoryChart>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, I have defined the events as a seperate variable to make things easier to read.

Also, each **VictoryBar** has a prop called `name`. This is used inside the `events` array to target different components.

If you compile and run this code, it will print different messages in the console when you click on bars.

Now, lets study the `events` array in more detail.

The `events` array contain 2 elements. Each element has properties - **target** and **childName**.

1. **target** - specifies which part of the graph you want to attach the event on. It can be *data* for (bar/line/scatter) or *labels* or *parent*
2. **childName** - it is used to target an element of the chart based on the `name` prop that we added to *VictoryBar*. Can be a string, array of string or 'all'

Thus, `{ target: 'data', childName: 'DataSet-0' }` will attach our event handlers on all `VictoryBar`'s with `name` prop equal to `'DataSet-0'`

3. **eventHandlers** - This contain different handlers for events. In the example, I have used `onClick`, but other events like `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` can also be used.

---

Each event handler returns an array of objects. Each object can have keys -

```js
{
  target: '',
  childName: '',
  mutation: (props) => {},
}
```

`target` and `childName` are used to specify which component of chart needs to be affected when event is triggered.

For example, when a bar in clicked, you can change the color of `VictoryLabel` or the chart using

```js
{
  target: 'label',
  childName: 'DataSet-0',
  mutation: (props) => ({ style: { ...props.style, color: 'orange' } }),
}
```

For more information about events check the [Common Props](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/common-props#events) page in Victory Docs or the [Events Guide](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/events)